# Upload Profile Picture hover box is inactive on "The Workplace"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-picture

The box you normally get to upload a profile pic:
[image]

Heres the box on the workplace:

[image]

I repro'd it on two browsers (Safari and Chrome), as two users, and on two machines.

The issue may affect multiple sites, but I can't repro it on the few others I tried, including Academia (I thought it might just be newly-designed ones.)

Comment: Yep, repro on Safari 7. But Academia's box works fine.

Comment: [Looks](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/grey-box-blocks-reviewing-edits) [like](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/z-index-issues-in-the-10k-tools-flag-queue) [yet](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/add-image-doesnt-work-on-chrome) [another](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/layout-z-order-bug-when-flagging-questions) `z-index` bug.  They sure messed up the CSS on that site. (And, apparently, all for the two little paperclip icons at the right-hand side of the header.)

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2366/168 "   issue is happening on the main Workplace site...
The issue may be the Z-index of the background when the dialog pops up. Using the developer tools, I get the following HTML for the gray box::

`<div class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 1000; opacity: 0.5; height: 2009px; left: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>`

If the z-index is placing it above (rather than behind) the dialog box, we won't be able to click any buttons..."

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The working name for the design was, incidentally, "Clippy's Revenge"

Comment: @gnat - the z-index of the image upload popup is 1010.

Comment: @TimStone, yes, but over time it became clear to us that the [Clipi ethos would reject revenge as an appropriate solution](http://www.gadiel.com/uploaded_images/StarWarsRevengeofJediTeaser-729070.jpg).

Comment: @Oded this tells nothing to me (I have only general idea of what z-index means), I merely quoted what was reported at TWP meta. jmac wrote this, not me :)

Comment: @gnat - fair enough... I forget not everyone does web-dev ;)

Comment: @Oded: It's those pesky [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), every time. Doesn't matter if the z-index of the popup is -999 or 1010 or over 9000, if it's nested inside a stacking context (`#header`) with z-index 2.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - I hear ya. I moved the z-index to the `:after` selector, which shouldn't have **anything** hanging off it (given most other sites don't have it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I moved some z-indexes around in the theme for The Workplace.

With you in the next build: (rev 2014.6.27.1685, meta rev 2014.6.27.2347)